# Little puzzle on functional programming in Python

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

The input is two integers in one line, x and y. I need to write a basically one-line program which does different things with x and y, and prints the result. Say, the output should be x + 1, y * y. Or list(range(x)), y // 2. Whatever operations but different. No def functions, also 'if' and 'for' are prohibited. As far as i understand, should look something like:

```
print(
    *map(
        lambda x: ??? ,
        map(
            int, input().split()
        )
    )
)
```

(But lambda can only do same thing to both inputs, right? )
I know it is possible and i've been thinking about this for three days to no avail. Most probable i miss something very obvious.

Comment: _Right?_ Wrong. You can pass as many parameters to `lambda` as you like.

Comment: Input many parameters - yes. Output a tuple - yes. The problem is that output = fixed function of input. Normally one would simply write:
    
x, y = map(int(input().split())
    
print(x+1)
    
print(y*y)

But it has to be done without intermediate x,y and in one line

Comment: `*map(...)` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lambda` function can take an `x` and `y` and turn them into pretty much any expression.  Then you would call that function, doing the processing of the inputs outside of that `lambda`

```
print(*(lambda x, y: (x+1, y*y))(*map(int, input().split())))
print(*(lambda x, y: (list(range(x)), y//2))(*map(int, input().split())))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a mental block indeed :) Very simple

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine:

```
print(
    *(lambda x: [int(x[0]) + 1, int(x[1]) * int(x[1])])(
        input().split()
    )
)
```

No fancy functional tricks or `map` are needed.

Comment: Thank you! I had a mental block indeed :) Several previous tasks in my course were heavy on map, filter etc.